# How to populate videos from C# on windows phone silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, video, windows-phone-8

I am creating a windows phone quiz app. it also displays short videos as questions which the users answers on. i have been able to use this code to display videos from a local directory. but my app package file gets so large if i will have to include too many videos locally. so i decided to try loading from internet once the users needs it. 
this is my XAML code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186" Margin="10,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436">
            <Core:SMFPlayer PositionLiveBuffer="0:0:9" EstimatedLiveDuration="0:0:30" VolumeLevel="0.9">
                <Core:SMFPlayer.SelectedAudioStream>
                    <Media:StreamMetadata/>
                </Core:SMFPlayer.SelectedAudioStream>
                <Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
                    <Media:PlaylistItem x:Name="media" DeliveryMethod="ProgressiveDownload" MediaSource="Assets/Kedike.wmv" MediaType="Entertainment" Title="song" FileSize="2413589" FrameRate="1045" VideoHeight="268" VideoWidth="512" Description=" vodeo" JumpToLive="True"/>
                </Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
            </Core:SMFPlayer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

This code works when the videos are loaded from a local source i.e /videos/kedike.wmv. i saw this code online and it actually was able to get a video with this:

```
mediasource = "http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/content/smf/smoothcontent/bbbwp7/big buck bunny.ism/manifest"
```

But to do this from the net, the DeliveryMehod property is set to ="AdaptiveStreaming"
i wondered what file type is that and i tried replacing the source with a youtube video link and a facebook video link. none of these works.
I need help in doing this. 
Then i want to change the mediasource programatically. i.e through the xaml.cs file. i think  declaring

```
media.MediaSource = new Uri("http://....", UriKind=Relative);
```

Dont know if this will work. 
I tried doing this since i have been able to load videos locally but i get error that i have not initialised or created a new instance of the media element (not the windows phone xna media) 
i got some other errors while trying to change some other things.
my C# CODE IS:

```
 private void secondvideo()
    {

        media.MediaSource = new Uri("Videos/kedike2.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

i want to play a second video with this code and i get error. this is the link to where i got the code.[code link](http://smf.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: I've never used SMFPlayer before, but seeing it's online doc AdaptiveStreaming is used for smooth streaming only. For common video streaming you dont have to change it from ProgressiveDownload.

Comment: And also "http://...." is an absolute uri instead of relative.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use any kind of link in MMPPF due to its limitation. You need to have the exact URL of the video.

Youtube videos' URL(the exact ones) are generally too large. If you really want to load youtube videos in MMPPF(though I think it's not legal to use Youtube videos in your own Media Player) use [this](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/) which is available via NuGet.

You can use this toolkit to fetch the exact youtube video URL and use it in your own player.